# Does gcc 4.3.4 support unique_ptr?

Tags: c++11, g++, unique-ptr

I've been trying to implement PIMPL using the g++ compiler on my local CygWin install and I'm beginning to think it may be the fact that I'm running g++ 4.3.4, inasmuch as its C++11 support is less than perfect.

With the very baseline code (from MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh438477.aspx)):

```
my_class.h:
    #include <memory>
    class my_class {
    public:
        my_class();
    private:
        class impl; unique_ptr<impl> pimpl(new impl);
    };

my_class.cpp:
    #include "my_class.h"
    class my_class::impl { int my_int; };
    my_class::my_class(): pimpl( new impl ) {};
```

I try to compile with `g++ -std=c++0x -o my_class.o my_class.cpp` and end up with:

```
In file included from my_class.cpp:1:
my_class.h:8: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'unique_ptr' with no type
my_class.h:8: error: invalid use of '::'
my_class.h:8: error: expected ';' before '<' token
my_class.cpp: In constructor 'my_class::my_class()':
my_class.cpp:5: error: class 'my_class' does not have any field named 'pimpl'
```

I also get that if I substitute `-std=gnu++0x`.

In fact, when I try to compile even the simplest file, lifted from another SO answer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<int> up( new int( 30 ) );
}
```

it complains that `unique_ptr` is not in the `std` namespace.

The [gcc c++11 support page](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) has no entry for `unique_ptr` but, from looking at the net, it's been around for quite a while, at *least* since 4.4.

So my question is, firstly, at what version of `gcc` was support for `unique_ptr` added?

And, secondly, am I just making some bonehead mistake in my code, using it the wrong way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first example, the `std::` qualifier is missing on `unique_ptr`. The second example [is correct C++11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=654132de92cce5f73a6c4998ce99a049-e1204655eaff68246b392dc70c5a32c9).

According to [the GCC 4.4 release notes](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/changes.html), `unique_ptr` was not in GCC's standard C++ library before 4.4:

> Improved experimental support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x, including:
>
> ...
>
> - `unique_ptr`, `<algorithm>` additions, exception propagation, and support for the new character types in `<string>` and `<limits>`.